# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, resources

I have resource `Resource1` have many strings doc1,doc2,...etc i want to retrieve all in this resource in list i make the following code but give me an exception when go to `foreach` loop this is my code

```
     ResourceSet resourceSet =  Resource1.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
    List<string> Data_set = new List<string>();

foreach (string xs in resourceSet)
        {
            Data_set.Add(xs);

        }
        listBox1.DataSource = Data_set;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cast `DictionaryEntry` to `string`, but you can get its `Key` or `Value`:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry xs in resourceSet)
{
    Data_set.Add(xs.Key + " " + xs.Value);
}
```